# Just started Intro to Python an have no previous knowledge about coding-That being said Professors rubric didn't explain anything any ideas

Tags: python, string, traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "challenges/str.py", line 7, in <module>
    result = 'a string combined with the number: ' + aString
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Hi Rebecca, welcome to StackOverflow. Please check out the [help] and [ask] for guidance on how to post questions here. Your question should include a title that describes your problem, a general description of what you are trying to accomplish, and a [mcve] which reproduces any problems you are encountering. Check out [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to help you format your code inside your question. Don't get discouraged by downvotes, you can always delete the question and post a new one, but please try to stick to the guidelines.

Comment: Note also, if you google this error message: "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" You should get tons of hits from stack overflow questions that have asked about this already. You should always try to google for questions that may have already been asked, this isn't the easiest thing to do when you are totally new, understandably, since you aren't even sure what you are looking for. But for many error messages, just googling it is quite effective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the lack of code, no explanation, it seems to me that the `aString` object is an integer.

To fix this, the line with error should become:

```py
result = 'a string combined with the number: ' + str(aString)
```

Hopefully, this helps!